# How to Inspect/Find an element in WPF for Automation Testing using Selenium Winium

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, winium

I need to automate testing for a WPF application using Winium.
I am unable to `Inspect Element` using `Windows Inspector` and `UISPY`

Is there any other tool which will help me with inspect element feature for a WPF application?

Answer (score 2):

You can find many GUI inspecting tools in this [link](https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool).

Such as:

- AccEvent.exe,
- AccExplorer32.exe,
- Inspect.exe,
- SPYXX.EXE,
- swapy-ob-0.4.3.exe,
- UISpy.exe,
- ViewWizard.exe,
- WSEdit.EXE.